# Which items of the NEO-FFI are a subset of the NEO-PI-R?

Tags: measurement, big-five

I am currently working on a NEO-PI-R dataset that is freely available online. To my knowledge the NEO-FFI is a subset of the NEO-PI-R. I would like to run a factor analysis on the NEO-FFI. Unfortunately, I do not have the NEO-FFI manual so I do not know which items make up the subset. Could somebody tell me the mapping? I do not think this violates any copyright since the items are not spelled out. I just need the item numbers (e.g. items x, y, z... of the NEO-PI-R make up the NEO-FFI agreeableness factor, ...).